# How many Zend Certified Engineers are there in the world?

Tags: php, certificate

I found [a tool](http://www.zend.com/store/education/certification/yellow-pages.php) on Zend site. But it is only show who have achieved ZCE by country.

I plan to take ZCE for PHP 5 and I just want to know how many Zend certified engineer available around the world.

Thanks...

Comment: As of AUG-23-2018, there are **13,845 certifications** (according to http://www.zend.com/en/services/certification/zend-certified-engineer-directory) in the world. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jy9u-84wf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about you, but if I was keen about finding out how many Zend certified engineers are available then I'd write some kind of a scraper that took the result for each country and sum it up.

... and do it in php. That would impress some employers.

Comment: I took you up on this challenge: As of AUG-23-2018, there are **13,845 certifications** (according to http://www.zend.com) in the world. Much lower than I expected.

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jy9u-84wf

Answer (score 1):

You can see how many are for each country and the sum up. There are not so many and some countries are more inclined to certifications than others. Spain has 42 ZCE which is very little compared with the total number of programmers or population. Israel doubles that for less programmers/ population. USA has about 1000, probably because big companies see in that a confirmation of your expertize, Microsoft style.

Answer (score 0):

I know one person who is certified.

When I finally get around to checking out the Zend framework, I'll consider getting certified.

If an employer requests it, I'll have no problems studying it and applying.

Comment: ZF is easy without any certs.